# Fetch each object of get-wmiobject as output

Tags: powershell

While using get-wmiobject for fetching sql services for servers, I am not getting proper output.

Script:

```
$server='XYZ'
$q = Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT * FROM win32_service WHERE name LIKE '%MSSQL% OR name LIKE '%SQLAgent%'" -computername $server | Sort-Object -property name | select name,startmode,state; 
$out= "$server" + "," + "$q.name" + "," + "$q.startmode" + "," + "$q.state" 
$out>>$path\output.csv
```

Output:

```
XYZ,Mssqlserver Sqlserveragent sqlserverbrowser,Auto Auto Manual,Running Running Stopped
```

Required output:

```
XYZ,Mssqlserver,Auto,Running
XYZ,Sqlserveragent,Auto,Running
XYZ,Sqlserverbrowser,Manual,Stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `$q` contains an array. The WMI query returns serveral objects, so it needs to be iterated. To include computername, add `systemname` to the property list.

```
$q= Get-WmiObject -query `
  "SELECT * FROM win32_service where name like '%mssql%' or name like '%sqlagent%'" -computername $server `
  | Sort-Object -property name | select name,startmode,state,systemname
```

Then it's easy to convert the result set as CSV:

```
 $q | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
"myserver","MSSQLSERVER","Auto","Running"
"myserver","MSSQLServerADHelper100","Disabled","Stopped"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will check above code and let you know if any further assistance is required regarding script